# Can only access asp.net app on localhost

Tags: iis, asp.net

I'm trying to get an asp.net application up on IIS on a Windows Server 2008 machine. I can hit the app from localhost, no problem. But I can't access the app using the server's domain name either locally or from another machine on the network.

But here's the odd part. I can access a normal file on IIS using the domain name, both from a browser running on the server and from a browser running on another machine on the network. Here's a synopsis ("http" converted to "htp" below because I don't have enough points to have all these links in my message):

From IE on the server itself:
works htp://localhost/foo.htm
works htp://localhost/App
works htp://test.foo.com/foo.htm
dead htp://test.foo.com/App

From IE on another machine (inside or outside my subnet):
works htp://test.foo.com/foo.htm
dead htp://test.foo.com/App

And when I say "dead" I mean the request times out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I worked this out.  Basically the app was redirecting to https, but only for remote connections, and IIS was not bound to 443.